# Stop AVPlayer and restart MP3 file again

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem

I want to start, pause and stop (same as restart) my mp3 File and I'm using AVPlayer. I get the files from a server.

To start the song I do:

```
[self.player start];
```

To pause I do:

```
[self.player pause];
```

but when I want to stop the song and reload it, so that the song starts from the beginning when the User clicks on the "start button" next time, I have no idea what to do.

I tried something like this:

```
[self.player pause];
self.player = nil;
```

But then the player is nil of course and I can't restart the file again without a new initialization. Any ideas how to stop it?

Comment: [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 5) completionHandler:nil] to play it from beginning again.

Comment: @Sandeep what is the second parameter (5) for?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Stop the video using `[player pause]`

Then use this code when you start the video.

```
[player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[player play];
```

I like this better than the comment that solved the OP it b/c it eliminates a warning and uses a constant.

Answer (score 20):

Best solution to do this in Swift < 4:

```
player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
player.play()
```

Swift >= 4:

```
player.seek(to: .zero)
player.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

- In Xamarin.ios

player.Seek(CoreMedia.CMTime.Zero);

player.Play();

Answer (score 2):

## seek#to has a completion handler.

```
p?.seek(to: .zero)
p?.rate = 1
```

is not really correct. You can get **audio jitter**.

```
p?.seek(to: .zero) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.p?.rate = 1
}
```

is probably what you want.

If it is *already playing*, and you just do the seek and nothing else, again you could get the jitters.

You are probably best to

```
p?.rate = 0
p?.seek(to: .zero) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.p?.rate = 1
}
```

If it's a really important app, you'll also have to consider the error condition in the seek completion.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4: `self.player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)`

Answer (score -1):

```
// If conti. play Video or audio apply this code



 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd
                                                 :)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[avPlayer currentItem]];
[avPlayer play];




 - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{

NSLog(@"Replay video in method");
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
  }
```

Comment: Because of poor code formatting and lack of explanation, this answer is not helpful.